# Why is cache being saved to the file system when Redis is configured as the cache backend?

Tags: cache, redis

I'm using a call to `Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')->save()` within a controller of mine and it's saving the cached value to the file system (`var/cache/`) even though Redis is configured as my cache backend, and seemingly all other cache in Magento is being saved properly to Redis.

Here's the save() call:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')->save($imageUrl, $cacheKey, array(Mage_Core_Model_Config::CACHE_TAG));
```

Here's my `app/etc/local.xml`:

```
<cache>
    <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
    <backend_options>
        <server>redis11.i</server>
        <port>6379</port>
        <database>2</database>
        <password></password>
        <persistent>cache-db2</persistent>
        <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
        <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
        <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
        <compress_data>1</compress_data>
        <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
        <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
    </backend_options>
</cache>
```

Why is it saving that cached value to the file system instead of Redis?

Comment: There are a few issues the same on https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed but none of them seem to give a very useful answer :(

Comment: Thanks David - good to know!  So are you experiencing this issue yourself right now?

Comment: Eh not really we have the cache folder but it is just empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using Mage::app()->getCache()->save() as the cache gets initialised in the getCache() method by fetching the config and setting this for the cache object, whereas the  Mage_Core_Model_Cache constructor does not do this, as far as I can see and it will revert back to the default caching model.

Did a quick test with:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')->save(now(), 'time123', array(Mage_Core_Model_Config::CACHE_TAG)); 

AND

Mage::app()->getCache()->save(now(), 'time12345', array(Mage_Core_Model_Config::CACHE_TAG));
```

Further info:

Mage_Core_Model_App::_initCache actually uses the following to set up the cache object:

```
$this->_cache = Mage::getModel('core/cache', $options);
```

Which means the core cache object is not added to the registry for use as a singleton. The first time you call it as a singleton a new core cache object is created and the constructor is called without any options.

Comment: Wow, I'm feeling a little bit sheepish right now.  That worked!  Thanks!